# "no control matching name" in mechanize for python

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I am using mechanize for python and I am trying to search for an item in kijiji. Eventually my goal is for my program to search for an item, and using beautifulsoup, check whether or not someone has posted a new ad for my search term by scraping through the html source that comes from inputting a search term and e-mailing me if any new ads show up so that I can be the first one to respond. Below is my code, but I get an error:"no control matching name 'keywords". I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()  # allow everything to be written to
br.set_handle_robots(False)   # ignore robots
br.open("http://www.kijiji.ca/h-kitchener-waterloo")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br["keywords"] = "Nvidia"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK but there is no form named 'keywords' in the page. You can look into page source info to verify that.

Comment: I am looking to input data for the search box, which has a name of "keywords". The code should be br["keywords"] = "Nvidia", but that doesn't work either. If you right click on the search box and click "Inspect Element" you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Although this specific error I could not solve, I discovered an alternative way to tackling my ultimate goal which is to scrape a website and inform me of any changes. You can do this by changing the keyword found in the url(example:"kijiji.ca/monitor/kitchener-waterloo) to whatever product you are searching for, and then downloading the html source for that url on a timed basis and checking if the code matches the previous. If it doesn't, send an e-mail because you know a new ad has been posted.